# Finding differences between 3 complicated dictionaries in C#

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I am having trouble juggling 3 dictionaries to find differences such as missing entries and also property values.
The dictionaries key and values are these objects:

```
public class Car
{
    public string CarBrand{ get; set; }
    public string RentingCompany{ get; set; }
    public string CompanyPhone{ get; set; }
    public ComplexObj MyObj { get; set; } //This is a deserialized XML
}

public class Drivers
{
    public string DriverID{ get; set; } // Unique

    public string Name{ get; set; }

    public string LastName{ get; set; }
}
    public Dictionary<Drivers, List<Car>> List1 = new Dictionary<Drivers, List<Car>>();
    public Dictionary<Drivers, List<Car>> List2 = new Dictionary<Drivers, List<Car>>();
    public Dictionary<Drivers, List<Car>> List3 = new Dictionary<Drivers, List<Car>>();
```

I need to search in List1.Values all the CarBrands that are not in list2 or List3 and the save the entire KeyValue pair Driver and Value into a new dictionary.
I would gladly accept any guidance on what would be an optimal way to approach this.

Thanks

Comment: Should the new dictionary contain all the original drivers, even if they have no cars who's brand is not in `List2` & `List3`?

Comment: you can use selectmany to flatten the Car lists in dictionary and then check against it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach is going to be much much faster than comparing every car brand in list1 with every car brand in list2 and list3. The approach shown in the other answer has high computational complexity, it would scale badly for large amounts of data.

I haven't really tested it, but I think it is correct.

```
// only the distinct car brands throughout list2 and list3 remain in this hash set
HashSet<string> carBrandsInlist2and3 = new(
    List2.Values
    .Concat(List3.Values)
    .SelectMany(cars => cars.Select(car => car.CarBrand)));

// using a hashset for IsSubsetOf below is going to be much quicker than
// using a 'simple' IEnumerable because set operations have optimizations in place in case
// both sets are of the same type and have the same IEqualityComparer
HashSet<string> tempHashset = new();

Dictionary<Drivers, List<Car>> newDictionary = new(
    List1
    .Where(keyValuePair =>
    {
        // fill the temporary hashset with car brands of this kvp
        tempHashset.Clear();
        tempHashset.UnionWith(keyValuePair.Value.Select(car => car.CarBrand));

        // if tempHashset is not a subset of carBrandsInlist2and3
        // then in this keyValuePair there is a car brand that does not exist in list2 or list3
        
        return !tempHashset.IsSubsetOf(carBrandsInlist2and3);
    }));
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer you did indeed point me in the right direction. although i had to do the concatenation every list in order for it to work.. but certainly helpful.

Comment: @ElieK Can you elaborate on what "concatenation every list" means? If you mean using List1, 2 and 3 for `carBrandsInlist2and3` instead of just 2 and 3, wouldn't that mean that the lambda in `.Where` always returns `true`?

Comment: The problem was that using concatenation as implement above always resulted in actually joining the two lists together since List3.Values are objects from different instances and so the hashes are different. So i went ahead and flattened the lists further and used Concat on string values from List2 and List3, then used Concat on List1.

Comment: @ElieK That doesn't make sense, the only thing getting hashed in my entire answer are `string`s, which do not get hashed by their instance but by their content.

Comment: @ElieK (Reacting to the edit of your comment) The flattening before concating is redundant, since concating then flatenning should give the same result as flatenning then concating (especially for classes, which are not pass-by-value). What still confuses me though is what exactly you mean by "then used Concat on List1"

Answer (score 0):

```
var brands2 = List2.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Select(c => c.CarBrand));
var brands3 = List3.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Select(c => c.CarBrand));
var allBrands = brands2.Concat(brands3);

var keyValuePairsToSave = List1
    .Where(pair => !pair.Value.Any(car => allBrands.Any(brand => brand == car.CarBrand)))
    // or
    //.Where(pair => !allBrands.Any(brand => pair.Value.Any(c => c.CarBrand == brand)))
    .ToArray();
    //or
    //.ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
```